# Android dividing a little part of screen vertically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have two images next to each other.

Sure I am using "dp" as size, in some screens images become little and in some screens not. It's what dp does.

I don't know what I must set their sizes. 50dp, 75dp or 100dp... And also I don't know how to decide that.

I just want to give images' size to "screen size / 2" (because I have two images) and also want them scale their sizes. I mustn't give height. In any resolution, they must set their width to "screen width / 2" and height to proportional to their width.

Here is the graphic of what I want:

[image: instance]

What should I do?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set your images width into `screen size / 2`, make sure you are using `px` instead of `dp`, otherwise its result will be different on various devices due to the resolution of that devices.
You can get the width in pixels by below code.

```
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        displayWidth = dm.widthPixels;
```

After that you can set your image width by using this one.

```
       image_view.getLayoutParams().width = displayWidth /2;
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

The other way to achieve this is by make changes in your .xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ......
        ........./>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ......
        ........./>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So, do you think that's an elegant solution?

Comment: its a programmatical approach

Comment: I meant using px instead of dp. According to my knowledge it can be done using dp.

Comment: but the result will be different for various devices..Just compare the screen size of tablets and phones..

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_weight` attribute in `linearLayout`. In a `LinearLayout` if you set two imageview with same `android:layout_weight` then it will take same space. For Example

```
< LinearLayout
........
.......
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ......
        ........./>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        ......
        ........./>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It says: "error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'gravity' with value '1')."

Comment: Also for android:layout_width="0dip" says: "Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, should be used with layout_weight"

Comment: I'm sure @StinePike meant to say `layout_weight` in stead of `gravity`. That should also get rid of the warning you're seeing.

Comment: HI ,, sorry for my mistake .. I just lost my mid and wrote gravity instead of weight.. updated it .. I would definitely downvote myself for doing this :( ..